# How to compress image before inserting to wordpress using wp_insert_attachment function?

Tags: attachments, media

Is it possible that when user submit multipart form for creating a new post in wordpress, all the images are inserted using `wp_insert_attachment()` to media library with compression so the uploading time will be reduce?

Comment: the process of identify, compressing and uploading will probably be longer than just upload directly. you could use a plugin like `smush-it` to compress images once uploaded, but your users will need to compress the image themselves before uploading.

Comment: There are filters for that (of which I know none out of my head, but you can search this site). At least for JP(E)Gs, you can customize the compression ratio. The same goes for the max allowed upload size as well as the dimensions and max length/width of an image.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the point where the wordpress functions are being invoked it is too late to worry about the upload time as the file was already uploaded.

If you want to make the file smaller before it is uploaded you will have ti write your own code to do it in JS.

Comment: How using JS?
will you provide any example ? please

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, the most comfortable way is to use a plugin which handles image optimization and compression while the image is being uploaded. Those plugins also take care of optimizing your different image sizes too, so you don´t have to worry about that.

I myself have made positive experiences with both [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) and [Compress JPEG & PNG Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/), but lots of people use [WP Smush It](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/). Currently I am using the second one, because it seems to optimize images better than the first, but this might change from time to time, depending on how they are developed.

Image optimization should generally work losless or at least not visible to the end user. This is a quite interesting process, you can [read something about it here.](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html)